# I have experiencing problem to include a mutable variable as an argument for security function

Tags: pine-script

I try to use multi timeframe in ATR Trailing Stop in a strategy.
I don't know how to put these arguments for security function.
The problem shows within the last 3 lines, "Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the request.security function"

```
ATRTimeframe = input.timeframe(title="ATR Timeframe", defval="")
ATRPeriod = input.int(10, "ATR Period")
ATRMultiplier = input.float(3, "ATR Multiplier", step=.1)

ATR = ta.atr(ATRPeriod)
Stop = ATRMultiplier*ATR

var ATRTrailingStop = 0.0
ATRTrailingStop := if close>ATRTrailingStop[1] and close[1]>ATRTrailingStop[1]
    math.max(ATRTrailingStop[1], close-Stop)
else if close<ATRTrailingStop[1] and close[1]<ATRTrailingStop[1]
    math.min(ATRTrailingStop[1], close+Stop)
else if close>ATRTrailingStop[1]
    close-Stop 
else 
    close+Stop

var Position = 0.0
Position := if close[1]<ATRTrailingStop[1] and close>ATRTrailingStop[1]
    1
else if close[1]>ATRTrailingStop[1] and close<ATRTrailingStop[1]
    -1
else
    Position[1]

ATRSecure = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, ATRTimeframe, ATRTrailingStop, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off)

PlotColor = Position == -1 ? color.red: Position == 1 ? color.green : color.blue
plot(ATRSecure, color=PlotColor, linewidth=input(1, "Line Width", group=atrGroup), title="ATR Trailing Stop")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mutable variables inside `request.security()`, but only if you wrap them into a function. `Security` extracts the variable from the context of the current symbol and calculates it on a different symbol/timeframe, so it requires you to "package" everything that changes the variable into a function and request the function instead. Here's how that might look in your case:

```
<...>
atrStop() =>
    var ATRTrailingStop = 0.0
    ATRTrailingStop := if close>ATRTrailingStop[1] and close[1]>ATRTrailingStop[1]
        math.max(ATRTrailingStop[1], close-Stop)
    else if close<ATRTrailingStop[1] and close[1]<ATRTrailingStop[1]
        math.min(ATRTrailingStop[1], close+Stop)
    else if close>ATRTrailingStop[1]
        close-Stop 
    else 
        close+Stop

ATRTrailingStop = atrStop()
var Position = 0.0
Position := if close[1]<ATRTrailingStop[1] and close>ATRTrailingStop[1]
    1
else if close[1]>ATRTrailingStop[1] and close<ATRTrailingStop[1]
    -1
else
    Position[1]

ATRSecure = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, ATRTimeframe, atrStop(), gaps=barmerge.gaps_off)
<...>
```